# How do I define a dataframe in R that contains the results of a mathematical operation on two columns of another dataframe?

Tags: r, math, dataframe, operation

I have a dataframe with the following column names and 19 rows

```
> [1] "X12C.Signal_Grn"    "X12C.Signal_Red"    "X11P.Signal_Grn"   
> [4] "X11P.Signal_Red"    "X7P_.A..Signal_Grn" "X7P_.A..Signal_Red"
> [7] "X8P.Signal_Grn"     "X8P.Signal_Red"     "X9P.Signal_Grn"    
>[10] "X9P.Signal_Red"     "X10PA.Signal_Grn"   "X10PA.Signal_Red"  
>[13] "X6PB.Signal_Grn"    "X6PB.Signal_Red"    "X12P.Signal_Grn"   
>[16] "X12P.Signal_Red"    "X5P.Signal_Grn"     "X5P.Signal_Red"    
>[19] "X9P2C15.Signal_Grn" "X9P2C15.Signal_Red" "X42Pa.Signal_Grn"  
>[22] "X42Pa.Signal_Red"
```

The class is data.frame. The question is how I could create a new dataframe that contains the log 2 ratio of columns 1 and 2 , then 3 and 4, then 5 and 6 and so on for all the rows in the original reference?

Comment: What is a log 2 ratio of column 1 and 2?

Comment: Hi Patrick. The columns have numerical values attached to them. The log 2 ratio will be the logarithm to base 2 of the value of row 1, column 2 divided by row1, column 1.

Answer (score 3):

This solution is not that pretty, but it does what you want.

```
# Generate some random data with column names on the same format as you have
df <- data.frame(matrix(runif(19*22), 19, 22))
names(df) <- sprintf("%s.Signal_%s", rep(LETTERS[1:11], each=2),
                                     rep(c("Grn", "Red"), 11))
# Calculate log2 ratios
l2r <- as.data.frame(lapply(1:(ncol(df)/2), function(i) log2(df[2*i]/df[2*i-1])))
# Give the columns comprehensive names
names(l2r) <- sub("Signal_Red", "log2ratio", names(df)[seq(2, ncol(df), 2)])
```